# Set frame height to zero in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble setting the height for a `UITextView` frame completely to zero even when it contains no text. Here's what it looks like (the red is the `UITextView`).

[image]

I've tried setting the frame's height to zero from my code as well.

```
var frame = bodyTextView.frame
frame.size.height = 0
bodyTextView.frame = frame
```

My labels can have a frame height of zero but this `UITextView` just won't get smaller than the line height.

Comment: Why not set it to `CGRectZero`

Comment: I just tried `CGRectZero` and it's also not working.

Comment: Is your textview inside a tableview cell?

Comment: It is, it also has constraints. 20 bottom, 20 left, 20 right, and 8 top attached to the upper label.

Comment: Then add one more constraint for height and make outlet for it and set it to 0 when you want it's height to 0.

Comment: then ofcrs your textview will have height coz your constraints are resetting it. Giving an answr please follow it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using auto-layout or size classes  ? If not use…

```
bodyTextView.frame = CGRectMake(bodyTextView.frame.origin.x, bodyTextView.frame.origin.y, bodyTextView.frame.size.width, 0)
```

If you using auto-layout, then you should set up a height constraint on `bodyTextView` and use…

```
heightConstraintBodyTextView.constraint = 0
```

Comment: This does answer my question and I got it to work. Not sure why I didn't think of that. However, I need to remove the constraint when the cell is not selected, so I'm coding that now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboard with autolayout? If yes then you cannot set the frame.

Try to update constraints instead of frame.